# error: bundling failed: ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file index.js

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

react-native: 0.57.0
yarn : 1.9.4
nodejs: 9.10.1

react-native run-android give me this error:

```
[android, dev] ..\..\../index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1)::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2018:07:12:00 +0000] "GET /index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.10.0"
error: bundling failed: ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file c:\wamp64\www\React\hello1\index.js is not computed
    at DependencyGraph.getSha1 (c:\wamp64\www\React\hello1\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:238:119)
    at c:\wamp64\www\React\hello1\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:168:56
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (c:\wamp64\www\React\hello1\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:11:657)
    at c:\wamp64\www\React\hello1\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:11:817
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)
```

Comment: I'm getting this as well. Did you ever get it resolved?

Comment: Yes.I have reinstalled node, yarn and react-native. And then it worked.

Comment: i Had the same issue.  and it was due to the rn-config.js file in the root.

Answer (score 20):

That looks like an issue related to metro.

Try to close console and in the project folder run:

```
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-* && watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache
```

then run 
    `react-native run-android`

For windows cleaning cache should be something like this:

`del %appdata%\Temp\react-* & del %appdata%\Temp\metro-* & del %appdata%\Temp\haste-* & del node_modules & npm install & watchman watch-del-all & npm start -- --reset-cache`
 (I haven't tried it on windows, probably for windows best option to remove node_modules would be to install `rimraf`)

If it still doesn't work check package.json and .babelrc. You should have something like this:

`"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.45.0"`, and  .babelrc configuration:

```
{
    "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

Comment: Yes, after asking here, I was doing tries, I got it work same as second option. By the way I am on windows, what is windows equivalent of `rm` command?

Comment: I am getting same error in GenyMotion emulator, `error: bundling failed: ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file`, I also tried with new emulator

Comment: Yesterday when I commented here, before that my problem was resolved, but my bad day, it is again same now. Metro bundler is stuck on 0% now.

Comment: Even this window command throw an error, but it did some process, and now app is running.

Comment: Just identify the step where windows command stops and modify/remove that step. Try to remove the / from node_modules/ or adjust that step.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181735/discussion-between-khemraj-and-florin-dobre).

Comment: The windows command i added is not tested, is just a draft of how it should look, to delete node_modules in windows I think best would be to use `rimraf`

Answer (score 4):

I used

```
npm install
npm audit fix
```

and then on different consoles

```
npx react-native start
```

Comment: yup, needed an `npm i`

Comment: npm install solved my isssue

Answer (score 1):

i just try:

`watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn install && yarn run dev`

and in my case, i uninstall and reinstall my app on emulator, then it works

Answer (score 1):

mac users: open terminal and follow:

1.npm uninstall -g react-native-cli

2.cd
3.cd .npm-global
4.cd bin
5.rm -rf react-native

6.npm install -g react-native-cli

Notice: if you are a Windows user go to your user folder and delete "react-native" folder instead of steps 2..5

Answer (score 0):

```
rm-rf node_modules && npm install && npm start
cd ios && pod install
```

Uninstall the applications installed on the devices and reinstall the app.

It worked for me :)